What’s the term for being asked to provide a specific example of a general claim?
Whenever I make a generic observation about something, a specific person always asks me to provide an example.
Ex. He makes the claim that no one has ever gotten sick from a meal [insert place here]. I point out that I’ve gotten food poisoning from that place, and he asks me when.
I recall reading that being unable to recall specific instances on the spot doesn’t disqualify the overall assertion, but I can’t find the term for it. What’s the term for being asked to provide a specific example of a general claim?

Is there a term for it?

Fallacy? It is only an annoying person.

You reply: February 20th, 2023 (or some date when you could have eaten there). Let the annoying challenger disprove it. Then turn it around and ask them how they know that nobody has ever "gotten sick" after eating at [restaurant], when your knowledge is from personal experience. Follow it up immediately with "your knowledge is faulty, if you didn't know that I got sick". And then when they begin to reply, interrupt them with "you are talking out your..."

This isn't really an issue of logic but of rhetoric. The other person is demanding unreasonable details to put you on the defensive. Don't say that, though. Just say, "Why do you ask? Are you calling me a liar? And if I give you a random date will you believe me then?"

Consider the possibility that your interlocutor is being perfectly reasonable and see where it gets you. Y'all in the comments should consider the possibility too.

Asking for an exemple is not a fallacy. You could be mistaken about the place where you got food poisoning (memory is unreliable after all), and the fact you can't remember when it happened or what you ate is a good indication of it. In a formal discussion, like a scientific controversy or a policy debate it actually would be required that you can provide details about your claim. In a casual discussion of course, you can't be expected to provide a detailed recording of your food poisoning experience. Just don't expect people to give strong credence to your claim if you can't support it.

It's alarming the number of comentors who just assume the OP's friend is being anoying or playing games when OP just describe them making a perfectly legitimate request for information to support an argument. Some people just can't stand being challenged when they make seemingly baseless claims...

In order or domain theory it could be said to be a realizer...

This is simply asking for specificity or an example. An example can help a person understand the general claim. It can also put aside doubts a person has about the general claim. And asking for more details about the example is one way to understand the degree to which the claimant recalls the particular example they've given. Certainly there are understandable reasons why one might not have a lot of detail about an example you've chosen on the spot (e.g. not being able to narrow down the date of a meal more than within a year or two).

"Placing an unreasonable burden of proof on someone or something" might be a fitting description.
Although:

This isn't a logical fallacy.
It relates more to when it's reasonable to accept some claim as true given some evidence, and to abductive reasoning (rather than deductive reasoning, where we talk about fallacies more commonly). And it also relates to respecting other people by provisionally (or for the sake of discussion) accepting what they're saying is true, when they're making a relatively mundane claim and there aren't many implications to what they're saying.
* For non-mundane / extraordinary claims, we might still accept that they're truthfully and accurately sharing their interpretation of an experience they had, even if we don't accept their interpretation. Although if someone tells you they flew around in the real world like Superman, most people share a common understanding that that isn't a thing people can do (and we know hallucinations are a thing). So one might doubt them being truthful (unless the other person is a small child or someone else who lacks a firm grasp of what's real). Someone might experience that in a drug trip, but one would hope they'd realise that's not a thing that actually happened (and thus they wouldn't share it as if it actually happened).

It's not always unreasonable.
In your specific example, it may not be too unreasonable to ask you to narrow it down to some broad time period, e.g. "a few weeks ago" or "a few years ago". This could help to establish whether that's likely to still be a problem. Although some might also use this to shift the goalposts and act like what they said is still true, when in fact they've shifted from "no-one ever" to "no-one recently" (or maybe to "it happens very rarely")... although hyperbole is also a thing, so it's complicated.
If they ask you for an exact date and time and who you were with, that would be unreasonable (unless e.g. you're in a courtroom and that's a relevant fact to whether someone else should go to prison). Exact dates are difficult, if not impossible, for most people to remember for most past events (especially ones that weren't life-changing).



For your specific example, depending on their intent, that might be considered a form of:
Shifting the burden of proof.
They make a claim, you say it isn't true, and rather than them defending their claim, they demand that you defend yours.
One can be pedantic and say your claim still has a burden of proof. But this is still someone trying to distract from the burden of proof they have, from the claim they made before your claim. This isn't a respectful and honest way to interact with others.
One can be more pedantic and point out that "no-one ever" cannot be demonstrated, but one can also point out that one should go looking for evidence before concluding that there isn't any (e.g. look at reviews for the restaurant or do a survey of people who ate there). A more reasonable claim would be "I don't know of anyone who's gotten sick from eating there".
"No-one ever" is also just an unreasonable claim on the face of it, given that many people have health issues that makes them sick even when they eat food that's otherwise perfectly safe. It would be surprising if that hasn't happened to anyone who's ever eaten there. But one might suppose they meant only getting sick from food poisoning and not pre-existing health problems.


What’s the term for being asked to provide a specific example of a general claim?

We all believe that certain general claims are true even though we cannot possibly prove the absence of counterexamples. So, it would be ridiculous to expect people to be able to verify all cases before they make a general claim.
However, we need to have a good reason to make a general claim. We should be able to prove that we have verified at least one case.
So, if you claim that all Italians eat pizzas, you need at least to know of one Italian who eat pizzas. This doesn't prove your claim is true but at least proves you have one good reason to believe it.
Failing to exhibit one case would prove that you believe something with no good reason and that you are irrational or dishonest.

You're mixing up formal logic and informal reasoning. In formal logic any claim howsoever wild is vacuously true over null quantifications. You only need to change your Italian example to All Italians on this SE site.... If there are none then all claims are true.  In informal language  one could say All bets are off

@Rushi I already replied to your comment. There is nothing else to say.

+1 "However, we need to have a good reason to make a general claim. We should be able to prove that we have verified at least one case." This is exactly the case. To assert a general claim and have no instance is to have no proof.

One example isn't necessarily "good reason to believe it". A single 7-foot person (or even a few dozen of them) is not a good reason to believe that all people are 7 feet tall. It's simply refutation of the opposite ("no one is 7 feet tall").

@Barnes "One example isn't necessarily "good reason to believe it"" If so then no number of examples will give you a good reason to believe a general claim. I already explained: it would be ridiculous to expect people to be able to verify all cases before they make a general claim. Belief starts with one. Certainty is something else.

The term for it, unsurprisingly, is exemplification. Whereas a fallacy is a misleading and erroneous argument, exemplification is a technique in informal logic and rhetoric, and functions as a means of strengthening an explanation. According to WP, the definition of explanation is:

An explanation is a set of statements usually constructed to describe a set of facts that clarifies the causes, context, and consequences of those facts. It may establish rules or laws, and clarifies the existing rules or laws in relation to any objects or phenomena examined.

Thus, exemplification strengthens the logos in the dialectic. Part of this reason is psychological, because understanding particulars is often easier than understanding universals. Part of this reason is logical because an example may serve as proof of the generalization. If you claim that gavagai are out of control and violent, and you cannot serve a single instance of gavagai violence, then it undermines the claim as there are no instances. Thus, it's a legitimate tactic to challenge in a debate someone to exemplify, as it also stands the chance of eliciting claims that themselves can be undermined.
Interestingly, there seems to have been a mildly popular rhetorical view called exemplification theory. Apparently, it argued that "an event is the exemplification of a property in an entity". According to this research, providing examples strengthen's the persuasive nature of a communication. According to the abstract:

Exemplification theory has been used to explain media and message effects across a variety of domains. However, the theory has been critiqued for lacking empirical support for many of its predictions and underlying assumptions. In this paper, we review exemplification theory, contrast exemplars with narratives, and report the results of a meta-analytical test of one of exemplification theory’s predictions. We found that individuals exposed to messages featuring exemplars reported stronger persuasion outcomes than individuals exposed to base-rate or non-exemplar messages...

